# C++ 'using' keyword in class hierarchy with function call operator and private inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, struct, using

I have stumbled upon something that I don't quite understand. I have a class hierarchy that uses private inheritance where each of the `struct`s defines a different function call operator. Oddly enough, the function call operator from the topmost `struct` is available in the most derived `struct`, despite the fact that a `using` directive is only used in the first derived `struct`. A regular function `foo`, though, is not accessible there, as expected. Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void foo() {}
    void operator()(bool) {
        std::cout << "bool\n";
    }
};

struct B : private A {
    using A::foo;
    using A::operator();
    
    void operator()(std::string) {}
};

struct C : private B {
    using B::operator();
    
    void operator()(std::vector<int>) {}
};

struct D : private C {
    using C::operator();
    
    void operator()(std::vector<double>) {}
};

int main() {

    D d{};

    d(false);  // <-- works!
    //d.foo(); // <-- error: ‘void A::foo()’ is private within this context

    return 0;
}
```

I happened upon this while trying to implement the C++17 `overload` object for use with `boost::apply_visitor` using pre-C++17 code. I solved it using recursive inheritance, where each object pulls in the function call operator of its direct base class like so:

```
    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct visitor : private T, private visitor<Ts...> {
        using T::operator();
        using visitor<Ts...>::operator();

        visitor(T func, Ts... tail) : T{ std::move(func) }, visitor<Ts...>{ std::move(tail)... } {}
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct visitor<T> : private T {
        using T::operator();

        visitor(T func) : T{ std::move(func) } {}
    };

    template<typename... Ts>
    visitor<Ts...> make_visitor(Ts&&... funcs) {
        return visitor<Ts...>{ std::forward<Ts>(funcs)... };
    }
```

I wanted to understand why all of the operators are available in the most derived object. That's how I came up with the above example. Compiler is g++ 11.1.0.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what's going on here?

Comment: Why do you expect a privately-inherited class method to be accessible in the derived class when it does ***not*** have a `using` declaration that makes it visible, unlike `operator()`?

Comment: there is a using `operator()` from the base class in every class, not only in the first one. You could do the same with `foo` too

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges.  In each of your derived classes, you have `using parent::operator()`.  That's what's importing the operators down the chain.  If you did the same thing with `foo` you wouldn't get a compiler error either.

Comment: Of course you're all right, thanks a lot! I get it :-)

Comment: Better to avoid recursion with variadic template (for compilation time), `template<typename... Ts> struct visitor : private Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; visitor(Ts... ts) : Ts{ ts...} {} };` should do the job.

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, of course you're correct, but I was trying to do it using pre-C++17 code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by others in comments, it turns out I just had an error in my thinking. The `using` pulls in **all** the operators available in the respective base class, including the ones that were imported by the base class itself, and therefore all the operators will be available in the bottommost object. `foo`, on the other hand, is just handed down to `B`.